# C# десериализация с вариативностью классов

Tags: c#, xml

Есть обьект типа

```cs
class Main
{
    public GenericType Property { get; set; }
}

class GenericType
{
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
}
```

и Property  может быть как типа A:GenericType так и В:GenericType. Как при десериализации используя дескриптор привести их к нужному типу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать атрибут [XmlInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(A))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
class GenericType
{
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Опередили на 15 секунд :-)

Comment: Спасибо. Почти то. Только вот оно добавляет атрибут в ноду "<GenericType xsi:type="MyClassNameA" type="A">". А надо чтоб разруливало тип по  type="A", или хотя бы как-то изменить, чтоб вместо MyClassNameA  было валидным просто А

Comment: Ага. Вроде бы [XmlType("А")] подходит. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще один вариант (иногда пригождается).

```
class Main
{
    [XmlElement("A", typeof(A))]
    [XmlElement("B", typeof(B))]
    public GenericType Property { get; set; }
}
```

Также важное замечание. Ни один из приведенных механизмов десериализации (ни мой, ни andreycha) не использует для выбора производного класса дескриптор!

Comment: Вот все таки уперся в проблему, что нужно именно по дескриптору ориентироваться. При том определенный набор дескрипторов должен оставлять класс в Base типе. Наверно. еще один вопрос открою.

Answer (score 2):

И так, что же делать, если надо все-таки по дескриптору.

Вариантов тут три (не считая полностью ручного разбора XML средствами чего-то вроде XPath или XLinq).

### Вариант первый, самый простой. Постобработка.

Десериализуйте XML в промежуточный тип, отражающий его структуру (при наличии xsd-схемы такой тип можно сгенерировать автоматически утилитой `xsd.exe`).
Потом преобразуйте результат в свой формат.

```
var main = new Main {
    Property = xml.Property.Descriptor == "A" ? new A {
        FieldA = xml.Property.FieldA,
        FieldBase = xml.property.FieldBase,
    } : xml.Property.Descriptor == "B" ? new B {
        FieldB = xml.Property.FieldB,
        FieldBase = xml.property.FieldBase,
    } : new GenericType {
        FieldBase = xml.property.FieldBase,
    },
};
```

И обратно так же (+не забыть заполнить дескриптор). Разумеется, если получается много строк или есть одинаковые фрагменты - следует такой код разбивать на подпрограммы.

Также в нелегком деле перегонки из одного формата в другой могут помочь такие инструменты, как [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

### Вариант второй. Обертка - десериализатор.

Можно написать класс, реализующий интерфейс `IXmlSerializable`. Этот класс будет искать во входном потоке дескриптор, выбирать на его основе подходящий класс-потомок - и потом запускать его десериализацию). Выглядеть будет как-то так:

```
public class PropertyWrapper : IXmlSerializable {
    private static readonly XmlSerializer
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GenericType));

    public GenericType Value { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader) {
        var xml = XElement.Load(reader);
        switch (xml.Element("Descriptor").Value) {
            case "A": xml.Name = "A"; break;
            case "B": xml.Name = "B"; break;
            default: xml.Name = "GenericType"; break;
        }
        Value = (GenericType)serializer.Deserialize(xml.CreateReader());
    }
}
```

Приведенный мною код не может десериализовать массивы байт (ограничение XElement.CreateReader).

Альтернативный способ - использовать свойство-обертку:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public GenericType Property { get; set; }

private static readonly XmlSerializer
    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GenericType));
[XmlAnyElement(Name = "Property")]
public XElement PropertyWrapper {
    set {
        switch (value.Element("Descriptor").Value) {
            case "A": value.Name = "A"; break;
            case "B": value.Name = "B"; break;
            default: value.Name = "GenericType"; break;
        }
        Property = (GenericType)serializer.Deserialize(value.CreateReader());
    }
}
```

Недостатки этого способа - те же самые.

### Вариант третий. Предобработка.

Перед десериализацией XML можно прогнать через XSLT-преобразование. Данный способ самый сложный - но его можно применять, если в проекте уже есть компонент, выполняющий XSLT-предобработку поступающих документов.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать вариант, описанный [здесь](http://www.softwarerockstar.com/2006/12/using-ixmlserializable-to-overcome-not-expected-error-on-derived-classes/): `[XmlElement(Type = typeof(CustomSerializerClass))]` (у `CustomSerializerClass` должен быть `implicit operator GenericType(CustomSerializerClass)` и `implicit operator CustomSerializerClass(GenericType)`). Позволяет убрать неизящный `[XmlIgnore]`.